# On linear transformation of the Weibull distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, linear-transformations

Consider the two parameters Weibull distribution $W(\alpha, \beta)$ and its cumulative distribution function:  $$F(x;\alpha,\beta) = 1 - \exp[-(x/\beta)^{\alpha}]$$

Consider the random variable $T \sim W(\alpha, \beta) $ and the linearly derived random variable $Z = \gamma T$ with $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}_+^{*}$.

What is the probability distribution of the random variable $Z$ ?

I tried this : as $Z = \gamma T$ then $Pr(Z \le x) = Pr(\gamma T \le x) = Pr(T \le x/\gamma ) $ (because $\gamma > 0$) then we get 
$Pr(Z \le x) = 1 - exp [ -(x/(\gamma \beta))^{\alpha} ]$.

So the cumulative distribution of $Z$ would be : $1 - exp [ -(x/(\gamma \beta))^{\alpha} ]$ ?

Conclusion :  $Z \sim W(\alpha, \gamma \beta)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2988882/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: I tried this : as $Z = \gamma T$ then $Pr(Z \le x) = Pr(\gamma T \le x) = Pr(T \le x/\gamma ) $ (because $\gamma > 0$) then we get 
$Pr(Z \le x) = 1 - exp [ -(x/(\gamma \lambda))^{k} ]$.

So the cumulative distribution of $Z$ would be : $1 - exp [ -(x/(\gamma \lambda))^{k} ]$ ?

Comment: Your work is correct and so is the conclusion.

Comment: Great ! Thank you :)

Comment: The only thing I would add is to write the distribution function as a piecewise function where you mention that $F(x;\alpha,\beta)=...$ if $x>0$ and it equals $0$ otherwise.